# Sample group with replacement

Tags: r, random

I have a dataset of 273 individuals (groups) and over 2000 measurement on them (unbalanced). I want to create a random sample with replacement of the individuals including all their measurements. 

 Is there any smart way to do it or do I have to create new dataset and repeatedly add new data row by row?

EDIT: 
My dataset looks like this:

```
 id time quantil 
  1  124  0.245 
  1  178  0.324 
  2  304  0.124
  5  102  0.178 
  5  752  0.724
  5  822  0.687
  ...
```

I want to create new dataset which contains random sample of 273 invidiuals with replacement and their measurements. So if my sample of invidiuals would be 2, 5, 2, ... my new dataset would be

```
 id time quantil 
  2  304  0.124
  5  102  0.178 
  5  752  0.724
  5  822  0.687
  2  304  0.124  
 ...
```

Comment: Use `sample(nrow(df), num, repl=TRUE)` as an index to `[.data.frame`

Comment: As BodedDust suggested, you only need to do `df[sample(nrow(df), 273, replace=TRUE),]` if your data was called `df`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
samp <- sample(unique(dat$id), 273, replace = TRUE)
```

will sample 273 IDs. These can be used to create the new data set. The `data.table` package allows efficient processing:

```
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
setkey(datDT, "id")

# create the new data set
dat_new <- datDT[J(samp), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```